# How to restrict openvpn route at server side even if client side using no-pull

Tags: openvpn

I know that client side openvpn configuration can use **route-nopull** and write theirselves route. But this may cause some secure problem, for example when you don't want to let vpn user visit some node through vpn gate.

So how to restrict route scope at server side even if vpn user modify their client configuration and write self-defined route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand it, route scope is specified in the `server.conf` file, like this for example:

```
# Add route to Client routing table for the OpenVPN Server 
push "route 10.8.0.1 255.255.255.255" 
# Add route to Client routing table for the OpenVPN Subnet 
push "route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0"
```

This tells your VPN gateway exactly what routes to push to connected clients.

If you're concerned about some malicious client configuring a static route at the client side to send additional traffic through the VPN tunnel, you *cannot* stop this, unless you have administrative control of their machine and can prohibit them from manipulating the routing table directly.

**However**, you *can* do though is ensure that your firewall on the VPN gateway is configured to only permit the traffic that you want to pass through.
Assuming you're using just a regular linux box with the typical [iptables](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/iptables-essentials-common-firewall-rules-and-commands)/[ufw](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/ufw-essentials-common-firewall-rules-and-commands) as your VPN gateway, you would just need to make sure those are configured with specific rules identifying exactly what traffic should be allowed, and then everything else would be blocked, so even if a user does send some unexpected traffic over the tunnel, your gateway just drops it.